# Read single DataRow effectively

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I searched and could not find a way to read single `DataRow` with `SqlDataReader`.

So I came up with this solution but I wonder if it is the best way for reading a single `DataRow`.

```
public static DataRow db_Select_DataRow(string strQuery)
{
    DataRow drw = null;
    if (strQuery.Length < 5)
        return drw;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection))
            {
                using (DataTable drTemp = new DataTable())
                {
                    DA.Fill(0, 1, drTemp);
                    if (drTemp.Rows.Count > 0)
                        drw = drTemp.Rows[0];
                }
            }
        }
        return drw;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339010/what-is-the-best-way-to-fetch-a-single-record-via-an-oledbconnection

Comment: @Tahbaza that does not read as DataRow reads columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I'd be inclined to think that the network round-trip and associated query on the server are probably an order of magnitude longer than any method you might use in your client-side code...is there a specific reason that you need to access a single row this way?

Comment: Stephen i really can not make sense of what you said. You are querying a database and you know that it will return 1 row. So you want to retrieve that row with a most effective way.

Comment: I guess I should have asked if this is just a general interest of yours or are you trying to fix a performance issue?

My point was that no matter the method you use to actually read that single row in your code, the time spent doing that is probably very insignificant compared to the time it takes your query to be sent to the server, processed, run, and sent back to your code. That's all.